# Deploying a SharePoint 2013 application on a live environment

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I am currently working on developing a SharePoint 2013 application on my development environment; but I have the following questions on how I will be deploying my work on the live environment or on the UAT environment.

1. I usually deploy asp.net web application using Visual studio by creating a web deployment package and then deploy it to the IIS on the live machine. So in SharePoint 2013 will it be the same way?
2. If I have developed SP-hosted and provided hosted apps and I install them in a site collection , so will they be deployed automatically with SharePoint or a separate deployment should be done?

Best Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use WSP packages to deploy your work on a live environment.